# Running telnet standalone - possible?

Tags: freebsd, telnet, bsd

So, this is what I want to do:

there is a local non-superuser and it can upload the file into /tmp.

Using this account, I download a telnet server package equivalent to what is already installed.

I modify some settings, setting all file directories into /tmp.

Then compile and run as a standalone telnet server.

Is this possible? If not, what makes this impossible?

Or as a non-privileged user, would there be any way to enable telnet?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but with several limitations:

- Since you aren't the superuser, your server cannot bind to the standard Telnet port 23, or any other port in 1-1024. (Larger ports should work, unless there are additional restrictions implemented.)
- Since you aren't the superuser, your server will only allow logins to your own account – it lacks the necessary privileges to switch to other users' accounts.
- The standard *telnetd* server doesn't support being run as a "daemon", only inside *inetd* – and since you cannot modify the system-wide `/etc/inetd.conf`, you would need to run your own separate *inetd* (or xinetd, or ucspi-tcp).

In other words, it is basically useless, unless you find a way to get root.